# MVC ModelError how to get value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app. At a particular point I manually added an error to the `ModelState`.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("duplicateInvoiceNumberOrganisation", "The combination of organisation and invoice number must be unique");
```

What I'm wanting to know is how later from the controller do I get the value of error.

I know I can get to the `ModelStateValues` by:

```
controller.ModelState.Values
```

and it's in there because it says:

```
Count = 1
    [0]: {System.Web.Mvc.ModelState}
```

But how do I actually get the `"The combination of organisation and invoice number must be unique"` out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string error = ModelState["duplicateInvoiceNumberOrganisation"]
    .Errors[0]
    .ErrorMessage;
```

or to the get the first error of the first modelstate item that has errors associated with it:

```
string error = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .First()
    .Value
    .Errors[0]
    .ErrorMessage;
```